# How do I append an item to the list when the item is a parameter of a class and is found in another variable?

Tags: python, list, class

[Click here to see my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcN27.png)

I keep getting the error 'fellowship' is not defined. Why is this?

Comment: Give a [mre], in the post, **as text**.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `fellowship` is not defined when you try to create the `hobbit` fiction. Reverse the order of the books in cell 9.

Also dont use variable names like `next` which are Python keywords.
And your if-statement is not correct. If you want to check if `sequel` is of type `Fiction` use type or `isinstance()`